# quasi-uniform convergence is almost uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Sure a sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to a continuous function do not necessarily converge uniformly. A good characterisation of this behaviour is that such a sequence converges quasi-uniformily (Arzelà–Aleksandrov theorem).

Does quasi-uniform convergence implies almost uniform convergence ?

Here's the [definition](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Quasi-uniform_convergence) of quasi-uniform convergence

A sequence of mappings $f_{n}$ from a 
topological space $X$ 
into a metric space $Y$ converging pointwise to a mapping $f$ 
is called quasi-uniformly convergent if for any $\varepsilon>0$ and any positive integer $N$ there exist a countable open covering $\{\Gamma_{0},\Gamma_{1},…\}$ of X and a sequence $n_{0},n_{1},…$ of positive integers greater than $N$ such that $|f(x)-f_{n_{k}}(x)|<ϵ$ for every $x\in\Gamma_{k}$

Comment: To me "almost uniform" is a measure-theoretic concept, while quasi-uniform convergence is a topological concept. So these two notions are essentially "orthogonal" (i.e. you could have any combination of them holding). But perhaps you have a different notion of "almost uniform" in mind, or you have some regularity assumption about the measure on $X$.

Comment: @Ian indeed I take `almost uniformity` in the measure theoretic way. It is easy to construct such quasi converging sequence with uniformity everywhere but on a countable set. Then, I want to know if we can construct a more complex example, perhaps derived from seem kind of cantor set, then perhaps it would imply that quasi-uniformity + derivability could imply almost-uniformity